# Can an Awakened Shrub become an Awakened Tree?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, creature-size, time, size-scaling

This question is irrelevant to most campaign settings so I'm mostly asking this out of curiosity and to see what others think.

Essentially the primary distinction between a Tree and a Shrub is height (Yes there are some other differences such as the number of perennial stems, but some definitions omit these characteristics as optional. In addition Junipers can be shrubs or trees despite being the same species making the distinction irrelevant) so if a recently planted Awakened Shrub grows to the age of ~30 will it then become an Awakened Tree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is entirely up to the DM, or at least I did not find a word on this in the rules.

So, just listing options, it could indeed become an awakened tree. It could also be ruled that the shrub stops growing when it is awakened, or that when it grows it also becomes more and more like ordinary tree, until it's big enough to be an ordinary tree. Or it could become a giant-sized awakened shrub. Or it could simply die when it stops being a shrub. Or something else.